# vagrant ssh -c and keeping a background process running after connection closed

Tags: linux, vagrant

I am writing a script to start and background a process inside a vagrant machine.  It seems like every time the script ends and the ssh session ends, the background process also ends.

Here's the command I am running:

`vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant/src; nohup python hello.py > hello.out > 2>&1 &"`

`hello.py` is actually just a flask development server.  If I were to login to ssh interactively and run the `nohup` command manually, after I close the session, the server will continue to run.  However, if I were to run it via `vagrant ssh -c`, it's almost as if the command never ran at all (i.e. no hello.out file created).  What is the difference between running it manually and through vagrant ssh -c, and how to fix it so that it works?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was struggling with this exactly. However, although it's not a direct answer to your question, I found that JetBrains Webstorm solves this problem for me. It integrates with Vagrant and lets me setup run configurations for Bash or Nodejs that run in the Vagrant box. These run configs can then be stopped and started right in WebStorm. Awesome.

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem when trying to run Django application as a daemon. I don't know why, but adding a "sleep 1" behind works for me.

```
vagrant ssh -c "nohup python manage.py runserver & sleep 1"
```

Comment: I tried a vast number of solutions that included elaborate redirects of stdout and stderr and providing /dev/null as input. This is the only one I've found that actually works.

Comment: @SandyChapman I just found this. Curious, though - what's the alternative.

Comment: @cricket_007 usually when you add a magical wait for something it's not ideal. It leads to shoddy code that is prone to breaking when running on different systems. I. This case maybe an alternernative is to run in a tmux session? Dunno, would have to try some alternatives.

Comment: In my case using pipenv:  `vagrant ssh -c "pipenv run nohup python ./manage.py run_long_backup --my-arg & sleep 1;"`. Seemed to do the trick. I can `vagrant ssh; tail -f nohup.out` to watch the command's output.

Answer (score 2):

Running nohup inside the ssh command did not work for me when running wireshark.  This did:

```
nohup vagrant ssh -c "wireshark" &
```

Comment: I don't understand this at all, but this worked for me as well. I actually ran `vagrant ssh -c "sudo -u otheruser -i some-script.sh"` and couldn't make it keep running. But nohup on my side worked. Any idea why this works?

Comment: I got the same result without `nohup` finally with `--no-tty` option for `vagrant ssh`.