# Creating a continuous background job during provisioning

Tags: vagrant

During the provisioning of a VM I want to start a job which shall run in the background. This job shall continuously check whether certain files have been changed.  In the vagrant file I reference a script which contains the following line (which does nothing but echo "x" every 3 seconds):

```
nohup sh -c 'while true; do sleep 3; echo x; done' &
```

If I run this directly in the command line a job is created, which I can check using *jobs*.

If I however run it from outside the VM using

```
vagrant ssh -c "nohup sh -c 'while true; do sleep 3; echo x; done' &"
```

or if it is executed as part of the provisioning nothing seems to happen. (There is no job & no nohup.out file was created.)

---

I tried the following two answers to questions which seem to address the same issue:

(1) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793081/2431655) suggests to "properly daemonize" which didn't work for me. I tried the following:

```
vagrant ssh -c "nohup sh -c 'while true; do sleep 3; echo x; done' 0<&- &>/dev/null &"
```

(2) The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327955/2431655) says to add "sleep 1" which didn't work either:

```
vagrant ssh -c "nohup sh -c 'while true; do sleep 3; echo x; done' & sleep 1"
```

For both attempts directly executing the command on the command line worked just fine however executing it via *vagrant ssh -c* or by provisioning didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works in my case

Vagrantfile provisioning

```
hub.vm.provision "shell", path: "script/run-test.sh", privileged: false, run: 'always', args: "#{selenium_version}"
```

I call a `run-test` script to be run as vagrant user (is `privileged: false`)

The interesting part of the script is

```
nohup java -jar /test/selenium-server-standalone-$1.jar -role hub &> /home/vagrant/nohup.grid.out&
```

in my case I start a java daemon and I redirect the output of nohup in a specific file in my vagrant home. If I check the job is running and owned by vagrant user.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked running commands in [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) like:

```sh
screen -dm bash -c "my_cmd"
```

in provision shell scripts.